# Finding the first Adjacent pair

Tags: java, arrays

Trying to find the first adjacent pair in my code. Adjacent meaning only two of the same in a row. If found, it is supposed to print out the index of the first pair found. In this case 44 would be the first actual adjacent pair in my code. Therefore it should return the index of 10. Here is my array that I am currently working with.

```
  int[] arr = {88, 88, 88, 63, 29, 77, 77, 77, 77, 50, 44, 44, 8, 0, 99, 99};
```

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like a homework problem you’ve made little effort to solve by yourself...

Comment: actually practicing a problem for a final exam I have and this is a practice problem, everything I try throws my array out of bounds.

Comment: just looking for a suggestion, don't need it solved.

Comment: Loop until array.length - 2 and compare with i + 1 and make sure i + 2 is different. And maybe add a test case in case it’s only the last two that are the matching pair.

Comment: Check element at idx and idx+1, see if they are the same. Loop array.length-1 times.

Answer (score 0):

I caved (sort of) - so here is a partial solution.

```
boolean pair = false;
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length - 2; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1] && arr[i + 1] != arr[i + 2] && arr[i] != arr[i - 1]) {
                pair = true;
                index = i;
                break;
            }
    }
```

Basically loop through starting at index 1 (as need to check the previous element), and end at -2 (as we are checking two ahead).

**Note:**

There are quite a few* edge cases that you will have to code yourself, such as:

- If there are only 0, 1 or 2 elements
- If the first two are the only pair
- If the last two are the only pair

<sup>*There may be more I've missed so feel free to update the answer if you wish</sup>